# Python - Insert numbers in string between quotes

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace every number in a string with the number itself but between quotes:

```
str = 'This is number 1 and this is number 22'
```

Result:

```
str= 'This is number "1" and this is number "22"'
```

I know I can use use this regex to replace every number in a string with another string:

```
str = re.sub("\d", "x", str)
```

but this would give me:

```
str= 'This is number x and this is number xx'
```

How to replace with the matched number itself modified?

Comment: FYI you should never use `str` as variable as `str` is a built in Python data type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `\1` construct to refer to matched groups.

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\d+)", r'"\1"', "This is number 1 and this is number 22")
'This is number "1" and this is number "22"'
```

Note the use of raw strings (prefixed with r) to avoid having to escape the backslash – you should be using a raw string for the pattern to match as well, otherwise the `\d` may be interpreted as an escape in the future.

In addition, the pattern `(\d+)` matches any number of digits in a row, rather than just one digit – without this, a string like `This is number "1" and this is number "2""2"` would be produced.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need regular expressions for something this simple:

```
>>> words = 'This is number 1 and this is number 22'
>>> " ".join('"{}"'.format(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in words.split())
'This is number "1" and this is number "22"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a backreference to the previously matched content in the replacement pattern. Syntax is `\g<Number>`, where Number is the number of the captured group or 0 for the whole match.

As you want to quote contiguous numbers as one and not number by number, you need to use  `\d+` as pattern, not just `\d`

Full code:

```
import re
str = 'This is number 1 and this is number 22'
pat = r'\d+'
repl = r'"\g<0>"'
print(re.sub(pat, repl, str))
```

See http://ideone.com/x5uLte

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture your number like so:

```
(\d+)
```

And the replace with back reference (+your quotes around it) `"$1"`

see here: https://regex101.com/r/oXsFX7/1

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
s = re.sub("([0-9]+)",r'"\1"' , s)
```

Also please avoid using `str` as variable as `str` is a built-in type of [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) in Python.

Comment: is there any advantage to using `[0-9]` over `\d`?

Comment: @asongtoruin they are identical I believe. I like `[0-9]` as I have more control. This also demonstrates how to specify range of chars like `[a-z] `

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re
str = 'This is number 1 and this is number 22'
for s in str.split():
    if s.isdigit():
        str=re.sub(s, '"'+s+'"', str)
print str
```