# Inserting numbers in between a word in python

Tags: string, python-3.x

Any idea how we can Insert numbers in between a word in python?

I have a word say "Temple" . Now I want output as T10e20m30p40l50e.

Comment: You need to do a search before posting a question. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364992/python-insert-numbers-in-string-between-quotes/42365179

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
word = "Temple"
ten = 10
twenty = 20
thirty = 30
forty = 40
fifty = 50
answer = word[0] + str(ten) + word[1]+str(twenty)+word[2]+str(thirty) + word[3] + str(forty) + word[4] + str(fifty) + word[5]
```

T10e20m30p40l50e.